# Session Variables Not Working In Website

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I'm trying to make a website with Dreamweaver CS6 which displays certain tasks assigned to you. The username is stored in a session variable called 'MM_Username'. However, something that I can't identify is going wrong. Both pages are written in php. Here is my log-in page:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/RoBros_To_Do_List_Database.php'); ?>
<?php
  if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
    {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }

      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
  }
?>
<?php
  // *** Validate request to login to this site.
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
  }

  $loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
    $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
  }

  if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
    $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "MainPageUser.php";
    $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "Invalid Login Page.html";
    $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
    mysql_select_db($database_RoBros_To_Do_List_Database, $RoBros_To_Do_List_Database);

    $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT Username, Password FROM users WHERE Username=%s AND Password=%s",
      GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));

    $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $RoBros_To_Do_List_Database) or die(mysql_error());
    $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
    if ($loginFoundUser) {
       $loginStrGroup = "";

      if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
      //declare two session variables and assign them
      $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
      $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;

      if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
        $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];
      }
      header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
    } else {
      header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
    }
  }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>User Login</title>
  <link href="Log-In Screen Styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="headBar">
    <a href="index(userLogin).php">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="RoBro's To Do List" longdesc="logo.png" />
    </a>
    <p class="headBarRight">
      <input type="button" class="signUpLinkButton" value="Sign Up" onclick="window.location='newUser.php'"/>
    </p>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class = "loginDiv">
    <div class="signInWords">User Sign In</div>
    <br />
    <form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" name="loginChecker" method="POST" id="loginChecker">
      <label for="username" class="loginLabels">Username:</label>
      <br />
      <span id="spryUsLogUs">
        <input name="username" type="text" class = "loginEntryField">
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span>
      </span>
      <br />
      <br />
      <label for="password" class="loginLabels">Password:</label>
      <br />
      <span id="spryUsLogPa">
        <input type="password" name="password" class = "loginEntryField"/>
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span>
      </span>
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitPass" value="Sign In">
      <br />
      <a href="adminLogin.php" class="logSwitch">Admin Sign In</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spryUsLogUs", "custom");
    var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("spryUsLogPa", "custom");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code which displays the tasks:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/RoBros_To_Do_List_Database.php'); ?>
<?php
  //initialize the session
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
  }

  // ** Logout the current user. **
  $logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
  if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")) {
    $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  }

  if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")) {
    //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
    $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
    unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
    unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
    unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

    $logoutGoTo = "index.php";
    if ($logoutGoTo) {
      header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
      exit;
    }
  }
?>
<?php
  if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }

      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
  }

  $colname_getTasks = "-1";
  if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
    $colname_getTasks = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
  }
  mysql_select_db($database_RoBros_To_Do_List_Database, $RoBros_To_Do_List_Database);
  $query_getTasks = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE `For` = %s ORDER BY Completed ASC", GetSQLValueString($colname_getTasks, "text"));
  $getTasks = mysql_query($query_getTasks, $RoBros_To_Do_List_Database) or die(mysql_error());
  $row_getTasks = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTasks);
  $totalRows_getTasks = mysql_num_rows($getTasks);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>
        To-Do List
  </title>
  <link href="Main Page Styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
  <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/aladin:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="headBar">
    <a href="MainPageUser.php">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="RoBro's To Do List" longdesc="logo.png" />
    </a>
    <p class="headBarRight">
      &nbsp; <?php echo $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?>
      <br />
      <input type="button" class="logoutButton" value="Logout" onClick="window.location='<?php echo $logoutAction ?>'"/>
    </p>
  </div>
  <br />
  <table width="800" border="1" class="taskTable">
      <tr class="tableHeader">
        <td>Task</td>
        <td>Uploaded By</td>
        <td>Completion</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <?php do { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_getTasks['Task']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_getTasks['uploadedBy']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_getTasks['Completed']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="taskAction" value="Set As Completed" onClick="window.location='completeTask.php?taskID=<?php echo $row_getTasks['taskID']; ?>'"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="taskAction" value="Delete" onClick="window.location='deleteTask.php?taskID=<?php echo $row_getTasks['taskID']; ?>'"/></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_getTasks = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTasks)); ?>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
  mysql_free_result($getTasks);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (empty(session_id())) {
  session_start();
}
```

replace ur session start with this code, because when $_SESSION is set, session will not start, so u can't acces to data

Comment: I have edited the code, but this has resulted in something very odd happening. My index page is displaying correctly. However, whenever I run my other programs in live view, they give the internal server error of: "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log." So, I can't test if what you said actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

you should not start the session like this

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

just use `session_start()` on the top of the script

Comment: Doing this didn't help.